# "message.content" doesn't work in DMs - Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried to make a ping command for a DM channel, so if an author says `ping` in a DM channel, a bot could reply `pong`, but it’s not working. The console is not giving any error and the bot is not providing any output.

`message.content` doesn’t work in DMs.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if(message.author.bot) return

  //command
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `ping`) {
    message.author.send(`pong`);
  }
});
```

[image: Screenshot showing DM channel chat]

Comment: It's just `message.content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Discord developers site and make sure that your message content intents are turned on, and everything should work fine now.

[image: Image showing that message intents are turned on]

Comment: oof, wish i knew that earlier lmao

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

While the [coco bar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72027568/message-content-doesnt-work-in-dms-discord-js/72028087#72028087) is something that needs to be done, it may not be the full answer to the problems you are having. Something else you will want to make sure that you have enabled in the bot code is your [intents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). Somewhere in your code you have a line that starts off like this (may not be exactly this):

```js
const client = new Client({})
```

Make sure you have your intents enabled there.

Example 1 enables minimum intents:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'DIRECT_MESSAGES'],
})
```

Example 2 enables all intents:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: 131071,
})
```

Example 3 enables all intents with [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials):

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: 131071,
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER']
})
```

UPDATE intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents; all intents are now 131071

Comment: Example 2 is not a good idea, you should not enable all intents. You should use minimal intents and partials

Comment: Please explain why it is a bad idea to enable beyond minimal intents, I have written dozens of bots, pretty expansive and most of them need all the intents. So I know why mine would need all intents, so my personal needs aside, what is the downside of enabling all of the intents for the general use @MrMythical

Comment: I doubt your bot ever needs all intents, like does your bot use dms and listen to guild scheduled events? You also shouldn't need to get unneeded payloads

Comment: Your client will create listeners for all possible events whenever you enable all intents, this will slow down performance of communication with the API and will create an uneeded load. There's a reason behind why the library instructs you to pick out intents and does not enable them all for you by default. Better to be efficient than lazy.

Comment: Yes most of my bots have commands that are only used in DM's as well, I also have a command to create a guild scheduled event and block most of the community from using the built in version, all guild scheduled events are logged into a sql database since the information deletes on them as soon as the close. and it isn't lazy, the only 2 intents I don't use is GUILD_WEBHOOKS and GUILD_INTEGRATIONS

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote, but most of your evidence has been based on personal usage, while me and Mythical are simply stating how the gateway and API payloads will affect client performance.

Comment: Which is exactly what I asked for, so that others can see the reasoning behind it, to make meaningful conversation and educate others. Hence why my comment stated " so my personal needs aside, what is the downside of enabling all of the intents for the general use " Your post answered that.

Comment: I asked for the explanation because just saying something shouldn't be done without explaining why, doesn't help someone out who doesn't know why you "shouldn't do it"

Answer (score 1):

`message.author` doesn't have any `content` property. If you want to check the message content, use `MessageComponent#content` as stated in the documentation.

Also make sure you enabled the correct intents and asked for verification if you bot is over 100 guilds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an intents

```
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
```

or

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS","DIRECT_MESSAGES","DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS","DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING"] });
```